# plotting rolling_mean (pandas) not working

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I know there's a bunch of questions on here regarding the use of the rolling_mean function in pandas - but I can't get it to work.

I'm new to Python, and the packages numpy,pandas etc.

I have a list of DateTime objects and I have a list of simple integers. Plotting them works without a problem. But I can't plot a moving average line to the graph!

I'm trying to use the [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments) to understand it but I still can't get it to work. This is what I have tried:

```
# code before this simply reads a file and converts dates into datetime objects and values into a list
x1 = date_object #list of datetime objects
y1 = values1 #list of integer values
plot(x1,y1) # works fine

t = pd.date_range(date_object[0].strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), date_object[len(date_object)-1].strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), freq='W')
ts = pd.Series(y1, t)

ts_movavg = pd.rolling_mean(ts,10)

plot(ts_movavg)
```

..I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

As you can probably quickly tell, I'm very confused. I think I'm missing the point of the Series object.

EDIT: (full traceback)

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-228-2247062d3126> in <module>()
     33 ts = pd.Series(y1, x1)
     34 
---> 35 ts_movavg = PD.rolling_mean(ts,10)
     36 
     37 ts_movavg.head()

C:\Users\****\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\stats\moments.py in f(arg, window, min_periods, freq, center, time_rule, **kwargs)
    507         return _rolling_moment(arg, window, call_cython, min_periods,
    508                                freq=freq, center=center,
--> 509                                time_rule=time_rule, **kwargs)
    510 
    511     return f

C:\Users\****\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\stats\moments.py in _rolling_moment(arg, window, func, minp, axis, freq, center, time_rule, **kwargs)
    278     arg = _conv_timerule(arg, freq, time_rule)
    279     calc = lambda x: func(x, window, minp=minp, **kwargs)
--> 280     return_hook, values = _process_data_structure(arg)
    281     # actually calculate the moment. Faster way to do this?
    282     if values.ndim > 1:

C:\Users\****\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\stats\moments.py in _process_data_structure(arg, kill_inf)
    326 
    327     if not issubclass(values.dtype.type, float):
--> 328         values = values.astype(float)
    329 
    330     if kill_inf:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Could someone show me how to plot a moving average line using the rolling_mean function?

Comment: try `ts_movavg.plot()`

Comment: No change, getting the same error

Comment: can you add the full traceback? also how does `ts_movavg.head()` look like?

Comment: Please see the edit. It doesn't allow me to invoke ts_movavg.head() because the error occurs when trying to set ts_movavg

Comment: ok, then this is not plotting error! what does `ts.head()` look like?

Comment: It might not be a plotting error, tbh I'm not sure why I'm getting the error! ts.head() produces the following:
2004-01-04    [0]
2004-01-11    [0]
2004-01-18    [0]
2004-01-25    [0]
2004-02-01    [0]

Comment: it does not even get into the plotting; so it is obviously not a plotting error; from what you have copied as `ts.head()` is seems like you have a time series or list; and that is the issue;

Comment: Could you be kind, and show a very basic example with a plot and then applying a moving average line to it using rolling_mean?

Comment: my guess is that the problem is in `y1`. can you just add to your question what `y1` looks like?

Comment: y1 is a list of numbers: The length of y1 is 528. So print y1 outputs :
[ ['0'], ['0'] ............. , ['32'] , ['35'] ]

Comment: as far as i can see, that is not a list of numbers; that is a _list of lists of strings_; this means that your code is broken; but if you just want to have a plot change `ts = pd.Series(y1, t)` to `ts = pd.Series([float(xs[0]) for xs in y1], t)`

Comment: That was the issue. God I was looking at the wrong place for the fault. Thanks! If you write it as answer I will happily accept!